# I've got two cursors on my screen on recent upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: mouse, 17.04, radeon, 17.10, wacom

I have a Wacom Bamboo tablet and a Bluetooth mouse (I prefer to use only the Wacom), and annoyingly, it seems the cursors work independently, one for each device, but my Wacom cursor seems to disappear when using it. I have tried disabling the mouse by removing the batteries and sensor (didn't work), installing a new Wacom driver or Cinnamon Graphics Tablet driver but still two cursors. I suspect it may be my graphics driver...my graphics card is a ATI Radeon HD 5450, and I cannot seem to find the proprietary drivers. I did not have this problem on 17.04. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have the same issue after upgrade to 17.10  on an Acer laptop with no graphic card. You can add on to the bug issue I created https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libwacom/+bug/1728187

Comment: It seems for now the best option is to switch back to Xorg.

Comment: Thank you Legolas and pomsky! I'll add a comment to the bug report, and look into switching back to Xorg.